# I cannot view tfs file difference in php eclipse

Tags: php, tfs, phpeclipse

Hi i am using php eclipse neon 3 and  tfs as source controller .

My problem is I cannot view the file difference in source control explorer change set. When I click on details getting this error

[image]

Please help

Comment: Copy the text from the error here, please.

Comment: @gukogg this is the error . "Error querying work items : unable to load specified jdbc driver class [org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver] " . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested at my side, everything works as expected.

```
Eclipse for PHP Developers

Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500
```

Please check if you have the `hsqldb.jar` under

```
C:\eclipse\plugins\com.microsoft.tfs.core_14.123.1.201709051449\libs\hsqldb-1.8.0.10-ebcdic
```

If not just try to download from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/files/) and copy it there.

If that still not work, just try to uninstall then re-install the Eclipse and the TFS Plugin.

Comment: Hi Andy ,  hsqldb.jar was missing . I downloaded and placed in the folder . Its working fine . Thanks for your help